# Construct a frame $\mathfrak{F} = (W,R)$ that refutes $\square \bot$

Tags: logic, modal-logic

> (Blackburn, Modal Logic, Section 1.3) Construct a frame $\mathfrak{F} = (W,R)$ that refutes $\square \bot$, to show that $\square \bot$ is not a valid formula.

I think I've solved this, but I'm not sure if my understanding of $\bot$ is correct. My solution is as follows -

Consider $W = \{a\}$, and $R$ such that $Raa$ (self-loop). If $\square \bot$ holds at $a$, i.e. $\mathfrak{F},a \Vdash \square \bot$ then $\mathfrak{F},a \Vdash \bot$ also holds (by definition of $\square$). However, $\bot$ cannot hold anywhere, so $\square\bot$ is not a valid formula (We have constructed a frame in which it is not valid).

Is my understanding of $\bot$ right? Is $\bot$ something that **can never be true, i.e. is always false?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.   $\bot$ is valued as false by its definition in propositional logic, so cannot be valued as true by any world in any frame of modal logic.

When $\mathsf W=\{a\}$ and $\operatorname R=\{\langle a,a\rangle\}$, then $a\Vdash\square\varphi$ if and only if $a\Vdash\varphi$.   Since $a\nVdash\bot$ by definition, therefore $a\nVdash\square\bot$ in such a frame and thus $\square\bot$ is not a valid formula there in.

---

More.

- The meaning of $~a\Vdash\varphi~$ is that "formula $\varphi$ is valued true in world $a$".
- The meaning of $~a\Vdash\square\varphi~$ is that "formula $\varphi$ is valued true in all worlds accessible from $a$."
- A valid formula is one that is valued true in all worlds of the frame.
- $\bot$ is valued false.  No worlds can value $\bot$ as true.
- Thus $\square\bot$ is only valued true in *worlds* which have no accessible worlds.
- Therefore $\square\bot$ is only a valid formula in *frames* which **have no** accessible worlds.

---

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Could you include a link to find it?

Comment: Someone has solved it, but here it is if you're still interested: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4016027/prove-that-sigma-vdashg-m-phi-iff-squaren-sigma-sigma-in-sigma-n-in