# Prove that $\Sigma\Vdash^g_M \phi$ iff $\{\square^n\sigma: \sigma\in \Sigma,n\in\omega\} \Vdash_M\phi$

Tags: logic, proof-writing, modal-logic

> **(Modal Logic, Blackburn, Ex 1.5.3)**: Let $\Sigma$ be a set of formulas in the basic modal language, and let $M$ denote the class of all models. Prove that $$\Sigma\Vdash^g_M \phi \Longleftrightarrow \{\square^n\sigma: \sigma\in \Sigma,n\in\omega\} \Vdash_M\phi$$

**My work:**

1. For the $[\Leftarrow]$ direction: Assume $\{\square^n\sigma: \sigma\in \Sigma,n\in\omega\} \Vdash_M\phi$, i.e. $\forall \mathfrak M\in M,\forall w\in W, \mathfrak M,w\Vdash \{\square^n\sigma: \sigma\in \Sigma,n\in\omega\} \implies \mathfrak M,w\Vdash\phi$. We want to show that $\forall \mathfrak M\in M, \mathfrak M\Vdash\Sigma \implies \mathfrak M\Vdash\phi$. Consider arbitrary $\mathfrak M$, and suppose $\mathfrak M\Vdash\Sigma$. So, $\mathfrak M,w\Vdash\Sigma$ for all $w\in W$ (some would like to write $\mathfrak M,w\Vdash\sigma$ for all $w\in W,\sigma\in\Sigma$ - but that notation doesn't add any value). To show $\mathfrak M\Vdash\phi$, we take arbitrary $w\in W$ and show $\mathfrak M,w\Vdash\phi$. Since we have $\forall w\in W, \mathfrak M,w\Vdash\Sigma, $ we conclude $\mathfrak M,w\Vdash \{\square^n\sigma: \sigma\in \Sigma,n\in\omega\}$. By assumption, $\mathfrak M,w\Vdash \phi$.
2. I'm stuck with the $[\Rightarrow]$ direction. Assume $\Sigma\Vdash^g_M \phi$ holds, i.e. $\forall \mathfrak M\in M, \mathfrak M\Vdash\Sigma \implies \mathfrak M\Vdash\phi$. We want to show that $\forall \mathfrak M\in M, \mathfrak M,w\Vdash \{\square^n\sigma: \sigma\in \Sigma,n\in\omega\} \implies \mathfrak M,w\Vdash\phi$. Let us argue by contradiction. Suppose, **there exists** $\mathfrak M\in M$ and some $w\in W$, for which $\mathfrak M,w\Vdash \{\square^n\sigma: \sigma\in \Sigma,n\in\omega\}$ but $\mathfrak M,w\nVdash\phi$. **What do I do next?**

I really need to be able to use the $\mathfrak M$ and $w$ above to construct some model $\mathfrak M'$ wherein $\mathfrak M'\Vdash\Sigma$ holds so I can use the assumption. I don't know how exactly that would help though.

---

**Definitions if you need them:**

1. $\Sigma\Vdash^g_M \phi$ - For all $\mathfrak M \in M$ (class of all models), $\mathfrak M\Vdash\Sigma \implies \mathfrak M\Vdash\phi$. This is the global semantic consequence relation.
2. $\Sigma\Vdash_M \phi$ - For all $\mathfrak M \in M$ (class of all models), $\forall w\in W$, $\mathfrak M,w\Vdash\Sigma \implies \mathfrak M,w\Vdash\phi$. This is the local semantic consequence relation.

Please help, thanks a lot! Hints are okay, and solutions are good too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a proof $[\Rightarrow]$ with some details omitted. Let me know if this helps.

Assume you have a countermodel to the right hand side of the equivalence, i.e. a pair $(\mathfrak M,w)$ such that $\mathfrak M,w\Vdash \{\square^n\sigma: \sigma\in \Sigma,n\in\omega\}$ and $\mathfrak M,w\nVdash\phi$.

In the next step, you should consider the model $\mathfrak M'$ which arises by removing from $\mathfrak M$ *all worlds which cannot be reached from $w$ via a directed path using the accessibility relation*. Note that $\mathfrak M'\in M$ as $M$ is the class of all models.

(Maybe you want to do the proof from here for yourself. Otherwise, the rest goes as follows:)

Convince yourself that removing such unreachable worlds does not have an effect on which modal formulas are true at $w$. So we still have (i) $\mathfrak M',w\Vdash \{\square^n\sigma: \sigma\in \Sigma,n\in\omega\}$ and (ii) $\mathfrak M',w\nVdash\phi$. Let $w'$ be any world in $\mathfrak{M}'$. By construction $w'$ is reachable from $w$ in $\mathfrak{M}'$ and so from (i) it follows (check!) that $\mathfrak{M}',w'\Vdash \sigma$ for all $\sigma\in\Sigma$. Therefore $\mathfrak M'\Vdash\Sigma$, and from this and (ii) you get a countermodel to the left hand side of the equivalence.

Comment: I see a problem. What if $w' = w$? We do not know if $\Sigma$ holds at $w$. I agree that it holds for all $w'\neq w$ - but to make the statement $\mathfrak M'\Vdash\Sigma$, you need to take care of $w$ as well. Right?

Comment: Without knowing the Blackburn book, I would assume that $0\in\omega$ and that $\square^0 \sigma:=\sigma$ by definition. Then $w$ is covered.

Comment: Wait, are we assuming that zero is inside natural numbers too?

Comment: It's a matter of convention, you'll have to ask Blackburn ;)

Comment: Haha alright! Do you see any way of doing it without assuming $0\in\omega$? Personally, I don't

Comment: Thinking about it again, the statement is false if $n=0$ is not allowed. Consider $\Sigma=\{\bot\}$ and $\phi=p$. Then the left hand side is trivially true, while the right hand side says "whenever a world has no successors, then $p$ holds at that world" which is false.

Comment: Right, thank you! I'm off to sleep now, but I'll rethink this problem with a fresh mind after, and then I'll accept the answer! I seem to understand the idea of it now